# Why does NFC uses Modified Miller Coding for slow bit rates but Manchested Coding for higher bit rates?

Tags: networking, mobile, encoding, tags, nfc

What is the fundamental difference between the two coding methods which decides which one should be applied ?

I read [here at Wikipedia NFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_field_communication) that Modified Miller coding is used in Active Device at low bit rates with 100% modulation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about coding schemes for RF communication without any relevant connection to programming in the scope of SO.